# A question about atomic operation and its c++ exposition

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I have a question about atomic operation, and its exposition in c++:

```
std::atomic<int> my_value{0};
 
//...
// executed on thread 1
int a = my_value++;

//...

//executed  on thread 2
int b= my_value++;
```

To me, std::atomic::operator++ ensure that my_value == 2 , **but does it also ensure{a=0, b=1} or {a=1, b=0} ?**

From what I understand only the increment operation is atomic, I somehow see this code as:

```
std::atomic<int> my_value{0};
 
//...
// executed on thread 1
int a = m_value;
my_value++;

//...

//executed  on thread 2
int b= my_value;
my_value++;
```

However I saw some implementation that seems to suppose that both affectation and increment are atomic... Why, and how ?

Thanks in advance for your time !

Comment: In first example ++ operation is atomic. In second one, each load and ++ are atomic but its combination isn't (you can get also a=0 b=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From what I understand only the increment operation is atomic...

That's wrong. **Both reading the actual value and (post-)increment** is a single atomic operation. It's the same as [`fetch_add(1);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add). Note that *"fetch"* in the operation name.